# How to render HTML styled leaflet label?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I need to add labels (not poups) to each existing marker on the map. I created `labelText` variable which stores HTML for a label. And now, when I'm using it with then strange thing happen - each label shows data from the whole dataset, not data assigned to individual point:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("map")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    coords <- quakes %>%
        sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326)
    
    labelText <- paste0("<b>Depth: </b>",coords$depth,"<br/>",
                                         "<b>Mag: </b>",coords$mag,"<br/>",
                                         "<b>Stations: </b>",coords$stations)    

    output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
    leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
      leaflet::addTiles() %>% 
      leaflet::setView(172.972965,-35.377261, zoom = 4) %>%
      
      leaflet::addCircleMarkers(
        data = coords,
        stroke = FALSE,
        radius = 6,
        label = ~htmltools::HTML(labelText)
        #label = ~htmltools::htmlEscape(labelText)
        #label = ~labelText
      )      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried different combinations of `HTML` and `htmlEscape` (or none of them) but it still doesn't work as it should. You can uncomment code for `label` and test how it works. What I need is html styled label with data for each individual marker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works fine if you `lapply` the `HTML` function to the `labeltext` vector:

```r
leaflet::addCircleMarkers(
        data = coords,
        stroke = FALSE,
        radius = 6,
        label = lapply(labelText, htmltools::HTML)
      )
```